# How do I remove the first few characters of a file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

I have several log file most have in excess of 1 million lines each.
I wan't to remove the first three lines of each file as well as the first 9 characters of the fourth line.

I can remove the first 3 lines, however, I've not been able to figure out how to remove the first 9 characters of the fourth line and retain the rest of the document.

Sample data:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-06-02 00:00:00
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-  username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

Desired output:

```
date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

Code I have so far:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    newname = os.path.join(path, basename + '-out' + ext)
    with open(fullname) as read:
        #skip first 3 lines
        for n in xrange(3):
            read.readline()
        # hand the rest to shutil.copyfileobj
        with open(newname, 'w') as write:
            shutil.copyfileobj(read, write)
```

Comment: Try adding `read.read(9)`  after reading 3 lines.

Comment: Do you _have_ to remove those bytes, or could you replace them with spaces? I ask because it would be much more efficient to overwrite those bytes then to rewrite the entire file (which you have to do if you don't want that whitespace at the beginning).

Comment: I do need to remove them, because the rest of the script will convert the file to a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    newname = os.path.join(path, basename + '-out' + ext)
    with open(fullname) as read:
        #skip first 3 lines
        for n in xrange(3):
            read.readline()
        # consume 9 bytes    <<<<<< ADDED THIS <<<<<
        read.read(9)  #      <<<<<< ADDED THIS <<<<<
        # hand the rest to shutil.copyfileobj
        with open(newname, 'w') as write:
            shutil.copyfileobj(read, write)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're 99% of the way there. The rest is to advance the read pointer forward 9 characters before copying.

```
    #skip first 3 lines
    for n in xrange(3):
        read.readline()
    # Skip 9 characters
    read.read(9)
    # hand the rest to shutil.copyfileobj
    with open(newname, 'w') as write:
        shutil.copyfileobj(read, write)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info...  although I couldn't get the read.read() options to work  the comment about moving the read pointer forward pointed my in the right direction.

I just went with the option of advancing the pointer position by 108 and then reading the file.

final code that worked:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    newname = os.path.join(path, basename + '-out' + ext)
    with open(fullname) as read:
        #skip first two lines
        read.seek(108)
        for n in xrange(0):            
            read.readline()
        # hand the rest to shutil.copyfileobj
        with open(newname, 'w') as write:
            shutil.copyfileobj(read, write)
```